# Using 'dynamic' default value in QGIS custom form

Tags: qgis, default, forms, qgis-customization

I am trying to make a custom form in QGIS to smoothen the digitizing process. For this purpose, I put the Edit widget (Layer properties, fields) of one of the fields on 'value map', and I loaded a .csv file containing a list of names. This works fine; values from the list can now be selected when a point is digitized. 
However, to make things faster, I would like the form to 'remember' the last value selected from the list and to use this value as default for the next digitized point(s) until a new name is chosen from the list at some point in the digitizing process (and then to stick to that value until a new one is chosen, etc.).

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try Settings->Options->Digitizing-->Other settings--->enable Reuse last entered attribute values (QGIS 1.8.0).